# do I need setTimeout when appending script to head via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function that is declared inside a javascript file that is included with jQuery append method:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = scriptUrl;
jQuery("head").append(s); 

setTimeout(function(){ 
  jQuery('.divClass').banner({
      duration: 2000
  }); 
},100);
```

I was thinking that there could be a problem when loading the script will take longer than the given time set in `setTimeout`.

If script was included inside html with `<script>` tag, then a browser would wait until the script is loaded. But is the same if I include the script with jQuery `append()` method? Do I need `setTimeout` in this case? How do I calculate the time required?

Comment: You could check in your setTimeout function if the desired functionality exists, if not, keep waiting and checking for it. That's how I implemented a chrome extension that was injecting itself into an application with 5 iframes, which was kinda hard monitoring loading of each.

Comment: You can also put the code inside the anonymous function directly to the file you're loading, or use an IIFE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JQuery's getScript method:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
    console.log( data ); // Data returned
    console.log( textStatus ); // Success
    console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
    console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

or native (taken from http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/):

```
function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }

    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you could use jQuery.getScript(). It is asynchronous though.